# Como asignar un unico ID a cada campo date-picker en un formulario en Django

Tags: django-forms, datepicker, bootstrap-3

Estoy utilizando `django-bootstrap3 (pip install django-bootstrap3)` para renderizar formularios y  `django-bootstrap-datepicker (pip install django-bootstrap-datepicker)` para aplicarles a los campos DateField un widget de calendario.

En mi formulario, tengo los campos `check_in` y `check_out` a los cuales quiero aplicarles juntos el efecto del date-picker, para lo cual hago esto:

```
from bootstrap_datepicker.widgets import DatePicker
class DateInput(DatePicker):
    def __init__(self):
        DatePicker.__init__(self,format="%Y-%m-%d")
    def build_attrs(self, attrs, extra_attrs=None, **kwargs):
        attrs = dict(self.attrs, **kwargs)
        if extra_attrs:
            attrs.update(extra_attrs)
        return attrs

class LodgingOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'check_in': DateInput(),
            'check_out': DateInput(),
        }
        model = LodgingOffer
        fields = ('other fields', 'check_in', 'check_out', )
```

En mi template estoy renderizando los campos de esta forma, incluyendo el `form.media` para aceptar efectos css y js en ellos. A grandes rasgos lo tengo asi:

```
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block body_content %}

{% block extrahead %}   {# Extra Resources Start #}
   {{ form.media }}        {# Form required JS and CSS #}
{% endblock %}

{% bootstrap_field form.check_in %}
{% bootstrap_field form.check_out %}
{% endblock %}
```

Cuando yo renderizo mi formulario, el efecto date-picker solo aplica para el primer campo renderizado es decir solo para `check_in` y no para `check_out`

- Check in

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Check out

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer para aplicarles el efecto date-picker a ambos campos?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Realizando un inspect en mi navegador, he detallado que el tiempo de ejecucion se genera un codigo JS el cual asigna el id `_pickers` para cada campo check_in y check_out, solo que el script llama al primero que encuentra y es por eso que para el campo check_out que es el segundo no funciona:

- Check in

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Check out

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acorde a esto, se esta usando el mismo id `_pickers` para los campos.
Como puedo asignarle un id unico a cada date-picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He cambiado el id `pickers` de esta manera: En la definición del formulario he sobreescrito el campo asignándole un selector id con un nombre diferente.

```
class LodgingOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'check_in': DateInput(),
            'check_out': forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'datepicker2'}),

            'country': CountrySelectWidget(),
        }
        model = LodgingOffer
        fields = ('check_in', 'check_out', )
```

Y en mi template he sobreescrito o llamado a la funcion datepicker de esta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker2').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            sideBySide: true,
           // format: 'DD.MM.YYYY' 
        });
    });
</script>
```

De esta forma ya tengo diferentes ids en cada campo de fecha y el efecto de widget de date-picker